# How to double quote the passed variable using sed?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

I am new to scripting. I want to add a double quotes to passed variable using sed. I have written the script file but it is not inserting the double quote. My script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

essid=$1
port=$2

sed -i -e "s/\(ssid=\).*/\1$1/" \
-e "s/\(key_mgmt=\).*/\1$2/" iwlist_details.txt
```

I want to replace ssid = "xyz" with ssid = "abcd"

```
network={
ssid="xyz"
key_mgmt=WAP
proto=WPA2
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="hello123"
```

}

when I run the script I get the following output

```
#./myscrip.sh abc WAP iwlist_details.txt


network={
ssid=abcd
key_mgmt=WAP
proto=WPA2
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="hello123"
}
```

How to add the double quotes around "abcd" ?

Thanks 
Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use double quotes. How should `sed` know you want them? To use double quotes inside double quotes, backslash them:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(ssid=\).*/\1\"$1\"/" \
   -e "s/\(key_mgmt=\).*/\1\"$2\"/" iwlist_details.txt
```

or use them inside single quotes:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(ssid=\).*/\1"'"$1"'"/' \
   -e 's/\(key_mgmt=\).*/\1"'"$2"'"/' iwlist_details.txt
```

I am not sure which one you find more readable.

Comment: @choroba You're thinking of `\2`, not `$2`. +1 for the 2nd solution though. user2678235 - why save $1 and $2 in variables `essid` and `port` and then use $1 and $2 again explicitly instead of using the variables in your sed script?

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you, I was about to leave and lost concentration :-)